# Combo Box with State Abbreviations

Tags: ms-access

I have a Combo box on my form in Access 03. I need help on coding the combo box so that when a user hits T (for example), it will jump to the first state that starts with a T, and if T is hit again it will move to the next state that starts with a T and so for, for any letter. Also should the row source type be a Value List or Table/Query? Thanks.

Comment: Is typing out the beginning good enough? Example:  "TEN" should pull up Tennessee, but hitting "TT" would not.

Answer (score 3):

No need to code my friend just set the rowsoruce to your query and then set the “Auto Expand” property to “Yes” and access will take care of it for you

Comment: The first 'T' that is typed will get Tennessee, but hitting "T" again will not pull up Texas.

Comment: @Jeff O. That is correct. To verify I went to a site where I had to select my state. When I hit "T" 2x or more it would scroll through all the "T"s

Comment: The "hit the first letter again" form of scrolling through a list *is* the web-combo paradigm, but *Access* combo boxen are *different*. Doesn't work that way. Instead, the user types the first however-many-it-takes letters of the desired item until it's distinct from the item above.

Comment: And let me say that the Access behavior is MUCH better, in my opinion, and I wish that web dropdowns used the Access method, instead.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, listboxes DO behave the way you suggest. If you're really set on this, you might use a textbox and listbox to "fake" a combo box. Of course, the reason it's called "combo box" is because it's a combination of two controls, a textbox and a list, so you'd be re-inventing the wheel, but you could then get the behavior you want.